# Binomial series expansion of this equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

I want to expand this seris in ascending power of x, up to and including the terms $x^3$. Give each coefficient as a fraction in its simplest form

$\frac{1}{(2+5x)^3}, |x| < \frac{2}{5}$

What I have tried:

1. $(2+5x)^{-3}$
2. $(2+5x)^{-3}= 2+(-3)(5x)+\frac{-3(-3-1)}{2!}5x^2 + \frac{-3(-3-1)(-3-2)}{3!}5x^3$

Then simplifying the expression:

3. $(2+5x)^{-3} = 2-15x+30x^2-50x^3$

Although, The question asks for the coefficient in fractions. Perhaps I approached this incorrectly?

Following the advice from the comments:

$(2+5x)^{-3}=2(1+\frac{5x}{2})^{-3}= 2[1+(-3)(\frac{5x}{2})+\frac{-3(-3-1)}{2!}\frac{5x^2}{2} + \frac{-3(-3-1)(-3-2)}{3!}\frac{5x^3}{2}]$

this is simplified:

$2(1+\frac{5x}{2})^{-3}= 2[1+(\frac{-15x}{2})+\frac{30x^2}{2} + \frac{-50x^3}{2}]$

Is this form giving the coeffcients as a fraction in simplest form, or must I replace $x$?

Comment: You can't do what you did at (2). You need to write $(2+5x)=2(1+\frac{5}{2}x)$ and take it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) is
$$(1+z)^\alpha = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{k} z^k = 1 + \alpha z + \frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2!} z^2 + \frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)}{3!} z^3 + \cdots$$ so we need to first write $$(2+5x)^{-3} = (2(1 + \tfrac{5}{2}x))^{-3} = 2^{-3} (1 + \tfrac{5}{2}x)^{-3}.$$  You forgot that the exponent $-3$ must also distribute over the factor.

Then the binomial series can be applied to the second factor $(1 + \tfrac{5}{2}x)^{-3}$ with the obvious choice $z = \tfrac{5}{2}x$, $\alpha = -3$, to yield
$$(1 + \tfrac{5}{2}x)^{-3} = 1 + (-3)(\tfrac{5}{2}x) + \frac{(-3)(-4)}{2} (\tfrac{5}{2}x)^2 + \frac{(-3)(-4)(-5)}{6} (\tfrac{5}{2}x)^3 + \cdots.$$

Your lack of the ellipses "$\cdots$" makes the equation incorrect.  You also again did not distribute the exponent for each term in the series, instead incorrectly writing $\tfrac{5}{2} x^2$ and $\tfrac{5}{2} x^3$ rather than $\tfrac{25}{4} x^2$ and $\tfrac{125}{8} x^3$.  The final result is

$$(2+5x)^{-3} = \frac{1}{8} - \frac{15}{16} x + \frac{75}{16} x^2 - \frac{625}{32} x^3 + \cdots.$$  The radius of convergence for this series expansion is $|x| < 2/5$.